# Spring AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests and simpleJdbcTemplate

Tags: integration-testing, spring-test

I am trying to write an integration test using `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`. I want to use `executeSQLScript` method of this class.

However, when `executeSQLScript` method is called, it throws `NullPointerException` because `simpleJdbcTemplate` parameter of class `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` is not getting initialized.

My code looks as given below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:test-services-spring-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "promoTransactionManager")
public class PromoBrickDAOIT extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private PromoBricksDAO promoBricksDAO;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        executeSqlScript("classpath:testdata/sql/PromoBrick_Create.sql",     false);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
    }

    @Test  
    public void testPromoBrickGivenBrowseTaxonomyNodeId(){
        String btxNodeId = "v1_12";
        List<PromoBrick> promoBricks =     promoBricksDAO.findByBtxNodeId(btxNodeId);
        assertNotNull(promoBricks);
        assertEquals(promoBricks.size(), 1);
        PromoBrick promoBrick = promoBricks.get(0);
        assertNotNull(promoBrick);
    }


    public void setDataSource (@Qualifier("promoDataSource") DataSource     dataSource)    {
            super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `@Autowired` on your `setDataSource()` method.

See the last NOTE in the [Dependency injection of test fixtures](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-fixture-di) section of the Spring Reference Manual.